# Reemplazar un nodo arbol busqueda binaria

Tags: c++

Necesito hacer una función reemplazar(nodo arbol, nodo arbol_nuevo) que reemplace arbol por arbol_nuevo.

Pero la estructura arbol no tiene un elemento para guardar cual es su padre.

La estructura es así:

```
struct ABB {

   int elem;
   ABB *left, *right;

};

typedef ABB *arbol;
```

Alguna idea de como encararlo?

Comment: Tienes que saber qué nodo necesitas reemplazar mirando en el padre. El padre conoce a sus dos hijos y, si necesitas cambiar uno de ellos entonces ya tendrás todo lo que necesitas... nodo del padre y nodos hijos del nodo a reemplazar

Comment: Debo necesariamente cambiar o bien la estructura arbol agregando un campo "padre" o que la funcion eliminar reciba como parametro al padre. Pensé que podría haber otra solución.

Answer (score 0):

#### Los nodos no son árboles.

He visto en StackOverflow en Español varias veces esta confusión, y me resulta muy curioso que tantos usuarios cometan ese error.

En el código que has facilitado estás haciendo un alias de puntero a nodo llamado `arbol`. Y eso es tan erróneo como decir que un escalón es una escalera, sinceramente ¿Te parecen lo mismo?:

[image]
[image]

> Necesito hacer una función [...] que reemplace arbol por arbol_nuevo.

Crea un objeto de tipo `arbol`:

```
class arbol {
    ABB *raiz { nullptr };
}
```

Ahora podrás crear una una función de reemplazo, que hará un simple intercambio de punteros:

```
class arbol {
    ABB *raiz { nullptr };
public:
    void reemplazo(arbol &a) {
        std::swap(raiz, a.raiz);
    }
};
```

Comment: Entiendo lo de que un nodo no es una estructura.
Y lo del codigo, lo que estoy buscando es crear yo mismo esa función reemplazar sin usar "swap" ni clases.
Gracias igualmente.

Comment: @Edu aclara tu pregunta, porque no queda claro qué es lo que necesitas.

Comment: fijate si podes lo que le comente a eferion

Comment: Si quiero eliminar un nodo de una estructura de árbol binario de busqueda, mi pregunta es ¿necesito si o si que la estructura árbol tenga un campo "padre" para poder hacer la eliminación o puedo hacer algo con recursividad para que no necesite posicionarme en el padre para hacer la eliminación junto al reemplazo necesario para mantener la cualidad de árbol binario de busqueda?

Comment: Sigue sin estar clara tu pregunta @Edu si quieres reemplazo no necesitas eliminar; si necesitas eliminar no parece que estés hablando de reemplazos.

Comment: Bueno, es que sabiendo como reemplazar sabría como hacer lo de eliminar nodos. Pero lo que me interesa realmente es eliminar nodos. ¿Me puedes ayudar a entender como eliminar un nodo de un arbol de busqueda binaria de manera recursiva y de manera eficiente (que no vuelva a recorrer el árbol desde su raíz principal)? gracias igualmente por otras cosas que me has ayudado en otros hilos.