# Pila en c++ hecha con una estructura

Tags: c++, pilas

Hola amigos en esta ocasión tengo un inconveniente con algunos pedazos de código que no entiendo. Este es el programa en general que encontré en la web:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
struct Nodo{
    int dato;
    Nodo *siguiente;
};
void agregarPila(Nodo *&,int);
int main(){
    Nodo *pila = NULL;
    int n1,n2;
    cout<<"Digite un numero: ";
    cin>>n1;
    agregarPila(pila,n1);
}
void agregarPila(Nodo *&pila,int n){
    Nodo *nuevo_nodo = new Nodo();
    nuevo_nodo->dato = n;
    nuevo_nodo->siguiente = pila;
    pila = nuevo_nodo;
    cout<<"Elemento "<<n<<" agregado a pila correctamente";
}
```

Las partes que no se:

- La estructura Nodo tiene anidad otra estructura Nodo. Tengo conocimientos de estructuras anidadas pero no cuando la que esta anidada tiene el mismo nombre que la estructura principal... eso me confunde ayúdenme por favor.
- En el método main, a colocado: `Nodo *pila = NULL;` Ese pequeño código declara un puntero de tipo Nodo, pero no entiendo porque lo hace dentro de main y no dentro de la definición de la estructura(entre la llave y el punto y coma).

Tengo entendido que es ahí donde se declaran variables de tipo estructura.

Comment: Yo te aconsegaria tener dos estructuras, una para Nodo, y otra la Pila, la estructura pila tendría el puntero al primer nodo, y al último. Cuando agregar un elemento lo agregas después del último.

Comment: Lo siento pero el texto de las imágenes no se puede copiar, se lee peor y seguramente, en el futuro, las imagenes dejarán de estar disponibles, lo que invalidará esta pregunta. Si quieres respuestas yo de ti empezaría por reemplazar esa captura por el código fuente

Comment: No puedo compilar imágenes.

Comment: Compañeros ya puse el codigo fuente del programita

Answer (score 2):

> La estructura Nodo tiene anidad otra estructura `Nodo`. Tengo conocimientos de estructuras anidadas pero no cuando la que esta anidada tiene el mismo nombre que la estructura principal... eso me confunde.

No hay motivo para estar confuso, mira esta imagen:

[image]

¿Ves una serie de objetos que contienen en su interior otros objetos iguales a si mismos? Pues lo mismo está representando la estructura `Nodo`.

Las pilas se caracterizan por las normas que siguen para añadir y extraer datos ([FIFO o LIFO](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_in,_first_out)), una manera habitual de almacenar datos en contenedores como este es crear una estructura que contenga el dato y apunte al siguiente dato del contenedor, creando así una cadena de estructuras.

> En el método main, a colocado: `Nodo *pila = NULL;` Ese pequeño código declara un puntero de tipo Nodo, pero no entiendo porque lo hace dentro de main y no dentro de la definición de la estructura.

En este caso tienes motivos para estar confuso, ya que no tiene motivos para hacerlo. Es una manera de programar que he criticado varias veces en este sitio, te aconsejo echar un vistazo a otros hilos en este sitio en que se trata el tema con más profundidad:

- [Tengo una lista simplemente enlazada ¿Cómo le añado datos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/169454/2742).
- [Reemplazar un nodo arbol busqueda binaria](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/154863/2742).
- [No se imprimen bien las listas doblemente enlazadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/111517/2742).
- [Concatenar dos listas simplemente enlazadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/116952/2742).
- [Listas dobles c++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/203412/2742).
- [¿Como lleno una multilista?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/167673/2742).

Answer (score -1):

Como bien sabrás, la particularidad de las pilas es añadir elementos al principio para que esos sean los primeros en procesar.
En este caso, las estructuras permiten incluir un puntero a otra estructura del igual. Fíjate que el atributo `Nodo *siguiente` no es una estructura dentro de otra estructura, es solamente un puntero a una posición de memoria donde se aloja la estructura siguiente.
Un código muy simple para añadir elementos a una pila sería:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
//Define un nuevo tipo de datos
typedef struct Nodo{
   int dato;
   Nodo *siguiente;
} nodo_t;
//Es el nodo que apuntará al primer elemento (No es necesario iniciar el atributo "dato")
nodo_t * cabecera;

void insertarPila(nodo_t * nuevoNodo){
   //Si la pila está vacía la cabecera apunta al nuevo nodo
   if (cabecera->siguiente == null) {
      cabecera->siguiente = nuevoNodo;
   }
   //Si la pila no está vacía, el nuevo nodo apunta al primero y la cabecera al nuevo nodo
   //De esta forma convertimos el nuevo nodo en el primero
   else {
      nuevoNodo->siguiente = cabecera->siguiente;
      cabecera->siguiente = nuevoNodo;
   }
}

int main(){
   nodo_t tNodo = malloc(sizeof(nodo_t));
   tNodo->dato = n;
   insertarPila(tNodo);
}
```

Ten en cuenta que la cabecera es sólo para controlar en todo momento el primer elemento, nunca se va a usar como un elemento de la pila, por eso, no será necesario darle valor a su atributo dato, basta con el puntero a siguiente.

Si adicionalmente quieres sacar elementos de la pila es más sencillo. El método sería algo así:

```
nodo_t * sacarPila(){
  //Si la pila no está vacía
  if (cabecera->siguiente != null) {
     //Obtenemos el primer elemento
     nodo_t * primero = cabecera->siguiente;
     //Para borrarlo, hacemos que la cabecera apunte al segundo (Si hay un segundo)
     if (primero->siguiente != null) {
        cabecera->siguiente = primero->siguiente;
     }
     //Si no hay un segundo elemento, apuntamos a null
     else {
        cabecera->siguiente = null;
     }
     return primero;
  }
  //Si la pila está vacia
  else {
     //Devolvemos null 
     return null;
  }
}
```

Para cualquier estructura de datos (pilas, colas, listas simplemente enlazadas, listas doblemente enlazadas, etc.) debes abstraerte de las estructuras del lenguaje de programación y comprender primero el concepto que quieres implementar.

**Tip:** Los diagramas (dibujos) ayudan mucho.

Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero, tu respuesta me ah ayudado a entender casi todo lo que antes no entendia. Ahora me toca repasar algunas palabras reservadas que aun no conosco, para que asi todo me quede totalmente claro.

Comment: ¿Por qué usas `typedef struct Nodo { } nodo_t;` en C++? ¿¿??